# C - address of ptr to int list passed as void ptr - use int or const int?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, void-pointers

I have an `int* intList` and I am passing`&intList` to a function taking a `void*`. The function does something like:

```
int** ptr = voidPtr;
*ptr = malloc(...)
for(...)
{
   (*ptr)[i] = ...
}
```

My intuition tells me I should leave it as `int* intList`, given what the function does. But I also know the contents of the int list should never be modified outside of that one function, so would it ever be correct to have `const int* intList`? Or is that bad design?

Comment: It isn't clear how it wont be modified if it is later will be to free?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking the address of a pointer, your function should return a `const int *` which can then be assigned to a variable of the same type.

For example:

```
const int *getList()
{
    int *ptr = malloc(...)
    for(...)
    {
        ptr[i] = ...
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
const int *intList = getList();
```

This prevents changes like `intList[0] = 4`.  The only thing you'll need to do is cast the pointer to `void *` when passing it to `free`.

Comment: I think this is a bad design, because `const` hints that the contents of the list will never be changed, so I shouldn't to `free` it (which is wrong). Another example, which conflict with your: `const char *foo() { return "foo"; }`